# How to make a copy of a char and not a reference in C++

Tags: c++, function, reference, g++, char

If I declare a function like this:

```
string hash (char* key)
```

then any change I make to key will also change it's value when the function exits, correct?

I want to make a copy of it in the function so that I can safely change it without changing the original value.

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
char temp = key;
```

How can it be done?

Comment: No, any change you make to `key` will be local to the function, since `key` is a copy of the pointer value. However, you can change what `key` points to. If you want to prevent that, you should have `const char* key`. That said, if you want a copy do what Jerry suggests. While pmr is correct, if you need to make a copy it's best just to let the compiler do it in the parameter list. It's less work for you, and cleaner.

Answer (score 9):

Probably the most obvious would be to change your parameter to a string:

```
std::string hash(std::string key) { 
    // ...
}
```

In a typical case, you'd want this to be a `std::string const &`, but in this case you *want* a modifiable copy of the original, so you pass the string by value. Since a string can be (implicitly) constructed from a `char *`, you can still pass pointers to char to it without a problem (and the compiler will construct a string automatically where needed).

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string tmp(key);
```

tmp will be initialized to a copy of key. Make sure that key is null-terminated otherwise this will end in tears. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) for a overview of `std::string` ctors.

Declare the function as `std::string hash(const char* key);` this will make it obvious that key will not change and protects you from changing it by accident.

Comment: I'll +1, but Jerry I think has the best answer. If you need a copy, might as well let the compiler do it.

Comment: @GMan: Definitely. His answer got even better as soon as I remembered the `Want speed? Pass by value` article on C++Next and the solution is more general.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
string hash(char key)
```

this will push the char onto the stack and just its local version will be used within the scope of the function.

Oh, reading it again maybe you want to copy a string instead that a single char, in this case you can use `strdup` but don't forget to relese its memory at the end of the function. Finally you can also use the copy constructor of `string` class if you are planning to convert it to a `std::string` anyway..

Comment: I think he meant to say "char pointer" instead of "char" in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax for copying a char array into `std::string` is a bit wrong. To make a copy of a string just do this:

```
std::string copy(key);
```

On seconds thought, `std::string = (char*)something` should have worked, as string defines an assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strcpy` if you want to keep the parameter as a char pointer.

The definition:

```
char *strcpy(char *destination, const char *source);
```

You also use `strdup`

Answer (score -1):

`char temp = *key;` I believe.